# Developing Flash Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash

For a web application I need a "Copy-To-Clipboard" function which copies dynamically generated text to the system clipboard. Unfortunately the ZeroClipboard library is not compatible with another library we use (I lost hours trying to fix this). So I switched to clippy (https://github.com/mojombo/clippy) which works like a charm. But now my company wants to change the whole Look-and-Feel of the clipboard object so I decided to develop my own Flash Object which should work in the exact same way as clippy but looks completely different. Also the only Software my company ownes is Flash Builder (and FlexSDk which is just the SDK the Builder uses?). So I tried my best and also got a working Flash Object (with some ugly workarounds like an invisible button over the image and label just to handle the click event and call the copy function) which really copies a String to the system clipboard (yeah), but my Flash Object is ~1MB big while clippy is ~5kb?

I assume that the Flash Builder is the wrong tool? And for this tiny project Flash Professional is the recommended one? Also on the Adobe homepage I cannot clearly read which product does what job. Can somebody help me to understand what exactly do I need to develop simple Flash Objects with functionality like copying text to the clipboard?

Thank you very much for any answer!

Comment: Do you created Flex Project or ActionScript Project? Why you decided to develop you own Flash Object? You can change Look-and-Feel of the clippy.

Comment: What do you mean "Flash Object"? That's not a terminology used in Flash Development so what is it?

Comment: By "flash object" I mean simple swf files such as the clippy swf. I am completely new to this ^^ ANd yes I started with a AC-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with "Flash Object" but if you mean that you use Flex to make an swf to put online, you're right that using the Flex framework will include a lot of code that you don't actually need. Hence the big size of your published swf. A better way to do that would not necessarily be Flash Professional, but to use another SDK like the newer AIR SDKs. You can even get a smaller end product with the Flex SDK, as long as you don't use the Flex classes (try starting an ActionScript project instead of a Flex project).

Comment: By "flash object" I mean simple swf files such as the clippy swf. I am completely new to this ^^ And yes I started with an action script project. But currently I dont know how I can get ride of the "flex classes" or even if I am doing the right things trying to put the image and the code into a swf file. But thank you for clearing some things for me.

Comment: Oh my god! I tried the FlashDevelop IDE with the FlexSDK and followed a simple hello world tutorial with pure actionscript and WOW! My end product is 5kb and WORKING. Thank you for making me rethinking the whole thing!